# Java, why can't we use null as package name?

Tags: java, null, package

I am porting [apitest](https://github.com/nvMcJohn/apitest) to jogl, one of the directory is called Null, so I was simply trying to use `null` as package name and Netbeans complains that it is not valid.

I know I am splitting hairs, but I am just curious.. I didn't find anything here or on google..

Does it have to do with the reflection, the name retrieving, something similar or something else?
Or is it like this by design, same as operator overload?

Edit: I know it is a reserved word, but in code..

Comment: Consider the statment `null.TheClass`, how should java know that you mean null as a package?

Comment: Right, this make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An identifier cannot be named `null` as the [language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) mentions:

> An identifier cannot have the same spelling (Unicode character sequence) as a keyword (§3.9), boolean literal (§3.10.3), **or the null literal (§3.10.7)**, or a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: package names are identifiers?

Comment: @elect They are composed of identifiers. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.3.1.

Answer (score 3):

in this case, `null` is a literal ([null literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-NullLiteral))in java language, you can not used as identifier...

According to [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html):

## Naming Convention:

> Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the
> names of classes or interfaces.
>
> ...

## In your case Following reference is important:

> In some cases, the internet domain name may not be a valid package
> name. This can occur if the domain name contains a hyphen or other
> special character, if the package name begins with a digit or other
> character that is illegal to use as the beginning of a Java name, **or
> if the package name contains a reserved Java keyword, such as "int"**.
> In this event, the suggested convention is to add an underscore. For
> example:

Comment: I am gonna accept yours (in 8m) since it is clearer for me and suggests a nice trick for my case

Comment: Technically `null` is not a reserved word. It is just a literal. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9.

Comment: Ah, then I guess AR.3 answer is also "technically" correct.. :) Anyway, +1 for the tip, Xoce, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is like this only by design.

As per Java Language Specification, 'null' is a keyword and you cannot use any of the keywords to identify any other thing than its prime purpose.

Although you can use Null with capitalized 'N' and similar for all other keywords that does not match case with predefined keywords.

Java discourages use of such poor naming practices.

Answer (score 0):

null is a value given to identifier. package is a identifier. it cannot be a value.